# Почему не импортируются аннотации Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Хочу создать Spring Boot приложение, но почему-то не импортируются аннотации Spring, даже не вылазит ошибка при компиляции, а просто вырубается процесс и останавливается всё. Что делать в таком случае?

Вот здесь не импортируются Спринговые компоненты, а вылазит это:
@org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
package net.proselyte;

```
@org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

}}
```

Вот помник:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>net.proselyte</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringBootCRUDapp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

В дебагере вылазит ошибка:

Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51461', transport: 'socket'

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51461', transport: 'socket'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вечная проблема

Comment: А где, собственно, сам запуск? У вас же пустой `main`. Что-то типа `SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplication.class, args)`;? Вы бы назвали ваш класс главный как-то по другому, что ли). К примеру `Start`. И добавили б в `main() ``SpringApplication.run(Start.class, args)`